# How to add a file to ClearCase database, but not in source control?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

On my project I have some files that are generated automatically, so you'd normally don't put those in Source Control.

But since this process takes a long time and they change quite periodically, I'd rather keep them in Clear Case database to not impose this process to every one that desires to compile the source that isn't directly related to these files.

*So, is there a way that I could add files on ClearCase UCM without creating a version tree?*

More directly, I'd like to know if there a way to only one version per branch. As if when delivering this file to the main branch, it would delete the old version an replace it by the new one.

I know that this is a bit unorthodox, but I ask this because I'm not interested by the generated files history and I'd like to save space in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is there a way that I could add files on ClearCase UCM without creating a version tree?

No.

Unless those files are radically different from one generation to the next, (or are huge binary), ClearCase would only record the delta, which wouldn't consume too much space.

One trick would be to rename the stream in which the import of the newly generated source is done, and create a new stream, in order to not have a *huge* version tree over time.